# How can I write to a file using C++ buider in an Android app?

Tags: android, file, fopen, fwrite, c++builder-10.3-rio

I'm using the community version of C++ builder (10.3) under Windows 10 to develop an app to run on a Samsung Galaxy A40.

One thing I can't seem to get working is saving the contents of TListBox to a file.

Being a newbie to Android, I'm not sure about where this file should appear and what rights I need.

I've tried the following in a function to save the contents of a listbox to a file, but can't seem to open a file to write to. It always returns -1 :

```
int hFile;      // File Handle
int ByteCt=0;

hFile = FileOpen("Shopping.lst", fmOpenWrite);
if (hFile > 0)
{
    for (int i=0; i<ListBox1->Count; i++)
    {
        ByteCt+=FileWrite(hFile,ListBox1->Items[i].Text.c_str(),
                                ListBox1->Items->Strings[i].Length());
        ByteCt+=FileWrite(hFile,"\n\r",2);
    }
    FileClose(hFile);
}
```

Is there something basic I've missed, or what ?

Comment: This does not have to do much with a list box. You better ask how to open a file for writing.

Comment: You could try to use a full path instead.

Comment: Thanks, changed tags...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`System::Ioutils::TPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TPath) class to determine various system paths that your app can access.  See [Standard RTL Path Functions across the Supported Target Platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms) for details.  For example:

```cpp
String FileName = TPath::Combine(TPath::GetDocumentsPath(), _D("Shopping.lst"));
hFile = FileOpen(FileName, fmOpenWrite);
// or: hFile = FileCreate(FileName);
```

But FYI, [`ListBox1->Items`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBox.Items) is a [`TStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings), which has its own [`SaveToFile()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.SaveToFile) method, eg:

```cpp
ListBox1->Items->SaveToFile(FileName, TEncoding::UTF8);
```

You are just duplicating what `SaveToFile()` already does for you.  So you don't need to write the strings manually - especially since you are not even writing them correctly to begin with!

`String` in C++Builder is an alias for `UnicodeString`, which is a UTF-16 encoded string. Its `Length()` specifies the number of `WideChar` (`char16_t` on Android) elements it contains, but `FileWrite()` deals in raw bytes only.  So you are writing only 1/2 of the bytes of each `String` since `sizeof(WideChar)=2`.  And also, `"\n\r"` is not a valid line break to use, either.  You would need to use `"\r\n"` or just `"\n"`, or use the RTL's `sLineBreak` global constant.  But worse, you are trying to write the `String`s in their original UTF-16 format but are writing the line breaks in an 8bit ANSI/UTF-8 format. So you end up with a mixed-encoding file, which many softwares won't be able to read correctly.

If you really want to write the `String`s manually then it needs to look more like this instead:

```cpp
int hFile;      // File Handle
int ByteCt=0, BytesWritten;

hFile = FileOpen(FileName, fmOpenWrite);
// or: hFile = FileCreate(FileName);
if (hFile > 0)
{
    for (int i=0; i < ListBox1->Count; i++)
    {
        String s = ListBox1->Items->Strings[i];
        BytesWritten = FileWrite(hFile, s.c_str(), s.Length() * sizeof(WideChar));
        if (BytesWritten < 0) break;
        ByteCt += BytesWritten;
        BytesWritten = FileWrite(hFile, _D("\r\n"), sizeof(WideChar) * 2);
        if (BytesWritten < 0) break;
        ByteCt += BytesWritten;

        /* alternatively:
        UTF8String s = ListBox1->Items->Strings[i];
        BytesWritten = FileWrite(hFile, s.c_str(), s.Length());
        if (BytesWritten < 0) break;
        ByteCt += BytesWritten;
        BytesWritten = FileWrite(hFile, "\r\n", 2);
        if (BytesWritten < 0) break;
        ByteCt += BytesWritten;
        */
    }
    FileClose(hFile);
}
```

However, rather than using `FileWrite()` directly, consider using [`TStreamWriter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter) instead, eg:

```cpp
int ByteCt=0;

std::unique_ptr<TStreamWriter> File(new TStreamWriter(FileName, TEncoding::UTF8));
// or: auto File = std::make_unique<TStreamWriter>(FileName, TEncoding::UTF8);

for (int i=0; i < ListBox1->Count; i++)
{
    String s = ListBox1->Items->Strings[i];
    File->WriteLine(s);
    ByteCt += (File->Encoding->GetByteCount(s) + File->Encoding->GetByteCount(File->NewLine));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Remy, that's not only pointed me in the right direction, but also pointed out some of the bad habits I've picked up over the years.