# SaveToFile in iPhone and Android using Rad Studio (C++Builder)

Tags: android, firemonkey, c++builder, rad-studio

In reference to the following 2 posts, regarding the use of `System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath()`:

[“Save to Files” on iOS (FMX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030724/)

[How can I write to a file using C++ buider in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62063576/)

Now I can save my data to an iPhone. But in vain, when running my app on an Android phone, I can't find my file in the phone.

Can somebody help to demonstrate how I can use `SaveToFile()` to save a file on an Android phone?

Comment: Have you read the docs for [`TPath::GetDocumentsPath()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath) and [Standard RTL Path Functions across the Supported Target Platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms) yet? On Android, `TPath::GetDocumentsDir()` is for "internal memory" that is private to your app. To access the file from the outside world, try [`TPath::GetSharedDocumentsPath()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath) instead

Comment: Thanks Remy. I'll try to use the other function. But, is that means I have to use different function for iPhone and Android app?

Comment: when interacting with things related to the OS, like the file system, that is usually the case, yes